# iterating through a list to look up data, and construct a string

Tags: string, emacs, iteration

Elisp newbie, looking for help with this.

I have this variable:

```lisp
(setq bibtex-completion-additional-search-fields '(tags keywords))
```

I then have a function, which, if this variable is set, then needs to iterate through those field names, and look them up in a data record, concatenate the resulting values into a string, which it returns.

Here's what the data looks like:

```lisp
("2009-03-01 Zukin, Sharon and Trujillo, Valerie and Frase, Peter and Jackson, Danielle and Recuber, Tim and Walker, Abraham gentrification New Retail Capital and Neighborhood Change: Boutiques and Gentrification in New York City article zukin_new_2009"
 ("date" . "2009-03-01")
 ("author" . "Zukin, Sharon and Trujillo, Valerie and Frase, Peter and Jackson, Danielle and Recuber, Tim and Walker, Abraham")
 ("tags" . "gentrification, retail")
 ("title" . "New {{Retail Capital}} and {{Neighborhood Change}}: {{Boutiques}} and {{Gentrification}} in {{New York City}}")
 ("=type=" . "article")
 ("=key=" . "zukin_new_2009"))
```

This is what I have for the function ATM, which I know is wrong. But I can't wrap my head around how to do this in elisp (I have more experience with Python and Ruby).

```lisp
(defun bibtex-completion--get-extra-search-data (candidate)
  "Return extended search metadata as string."
  (if bibtex-completion-additional-search-fields
      ; if the data is present, pull its value(s), join into a single string
      ; TODO FIX ME, this is wrong
      (format "%s" (cl-loop
                    for field in bibtex-completion-additional-search-fields
                    collect
                    (cdr (assoc field (cdr candidate)))
                    ))))
```

So with the example data above, the function should return that string "gentrification, retail". And if that record were to have a keyword field with "foo", the return string would be "gentrification, retail, foo" (or could just be space-separated; not sure it matters).

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple records containing those fields?

Comment: This function just takes a single record. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the keys in your data structure are strings, not symbols.  So, you could change your lookup fields,

```
(setq bibtex-completion-additional-search-fields '("tags" "keywords"))
```

but, using symbols as the `car`s in the `candidate` data structure is probably better (efficiency-wise I believe).

The canonical elisp for joining list into string is
`(mapconcat #'identity ...)`,

```
(mapconcat
 #'identity
 (delq nil
       (cl-loop for field in bibtex-completion-additional-search-fields
             collect (cdr (assoc field (cdr candidate)))))
 ", ")
```